# Logical Volume /dev/centos/root is extended but /dev/mapper/centos-root is not

Tags: linux, centos7, filesystems

New to Linux Fileservers and trying to extend /dev/mapper/centos-root 
This is a test server

The Logical Volume /dev/centos/root is 27.99GB large:

> --- Logical volume --- 
>     LV Path                /dev/centos/root
>     LV Name                root
>     VG Name                centos
>     LV UUID                pTluxe-mE75-6X38-DVUa-QjkH-fCTg-odhdzY
>     LV Write Access        read/write
>     LV Creation host, time localhost, 2018-09-28 13:08:05 +0200
>     LV Status              available
>     # open                 1
>     LV Size                27.99 GiB
>     Current LE             7166
>     Segments               2
>     Allocation             inherit
>     Read ahead sectors     auto
>     - currently set to     8192
>     Block device           253:0

But the filesystem /dev/mapper/centos-root is only 18G big

> Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
>   /dev/mapper/centos-root   18G  2.0G   17G  11% /
>   devtmpfs                 192M     0  192M   0% /dev
>   tmpfs                    204M     0  204M   0% /dev/shm
>   tmpfs                    204M  5.0M  199M   3% /run
>   tmpfs                    204M     0  204M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
>   /dev/sda1               1014M  129M  885M  13% /boot
>   tmpfs                     41M     0   41M   0% /run/user/1000

resize2fs returns the following error:

> resize2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013) 
>   resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/mapper/centos-root

Comment: The default filesystem in 7 is xfs, not ext2/3/4.  If yours is using xfs, you need to use xfs_growfs, not resize2fs.

Comment: That's right, it works by using xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/centos-root

Comment: You also might consider using `--resizefs` in your `lvextend` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thomas's note about --resizefs really needs to be an answer. You can do both LV size change and file system extend in one command:

```
lvextend -r --size 28g /dev/centos/root
```

Just the file system part is also exposed as the fsadm command, which you can run on both ext and xfs file systems.

```
  fsadm resize /dev/centos/root
```

Answer (score 0):

Thomas' & John's command is indeed the fastest.

To extend the Logical Volume and Filesystem at the same time: 
lvextend -L +5G  --resizefs /dev/centos/root

To extend the Logical Volume separately: 
lvextend -L +5G /dev/centos/root

To extend the Filesystem separately: 
xfs_growfs /dev/centos/root